# navigation component with navigation view android

Tags: java, android, android-architecture-navigation, android-navigationview, android-jetpack-navigation

I am trying work with navigation component. 
currently I have navigation view with menu. 
I implement `onNavigationItemSelected` in navigation view and detect click by
`item.getItemId()` when there is clicks on specific items, it do something that not navigate to fragment. for example:

```
 switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.nav_share:
            Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            sharingIntent.setType("text/plain");
            String shareBody = "shae StayTuned with friends bla bla bla and we can put app url in the google play " +
                    "if we don't will be sdk";
            sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, shareBody);
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, "Share via"));
            break;
        case R.id.nav_disconnect_user:
            FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();
            break;
    }
```

how I can achieve that with navigation component?
thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the navigation component you don't need to manually implement a `OnNavigationItemSelectedListener` since the `setupWithNavController()` method connects destinations to menu items matching the `android:id` between your navigation graph and menu items.

If you use a custom `NavigationItemSelectedListener` you are removing the original listener. In this case you have to call `NavigationUI.onNavDestinationSelected()` to trigger the default behavior.

```
navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener {
        when (it.itemId) {
            R.id.R.id.nav_share -> {
                // handle click
                true
            }
         }
         //Call the original listener
         NavigationUI.onNavDestinationSelected(it, navController)
         drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START)
         true
    }
```

Comment: these items not exists in the navigation graph because it is not fragment. so how the matching between menu items and navigation graph items occurs? or does I can declaring not just fragment in  navigation graph?

Comment: @YaffaHarari Just specify in your `setNavigationItemSelectedListener` the items that **don't** match with the navigation graph. And for the others just use the default `NavigationUI.onNavDestinationSelected(it, navController)`

Comment: ok. I understood you. implement orginal `setNavigationItemSelectedListener` and remove `NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(binding.navView, navController);` from the onCreate and  put it per item at the end of `onNavigationItemSelected` method for other items clicks. it is work. thank you